# overflow error when passing wei value to EIP712 _signTypedData

Tags: ethers.js, overflow, eip712

```
    const domainSeparator = {
        chainId: 5
    };
    
    const TestInfo = [
        { name: 'contractAddress', type: 'address' },
        { name: 'fee', type: 'uint256' }
      ];

    const data = {
        contractAddress: '.....',     
        airdropFee: 52009946125155410 // wei value
    };
    
    const signature = await signer._signTypedData(domainSeparator, { TestInfo }, data);
```

> reason: 'overflow',
> code: 'NUMERIC_FAULT',
> fault: 'overflow',
> operation: 'BigNumber.from',
> value: 52009946125155410

solidity function takes `uint256` wei value for weth amount as an argument, so I'm sending that number but getting overflow error. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value `52009946125155410`  is above the maximum integer safely representable as a `Number` type in JavaScript: `9007199254740991` so ethers.js throws an [error](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/33a029e457320a226c68a01f4cfa2d110125a8b8/packages/bignumber/src.ts/bignumber.ts#L248).

Just pass it as a string :

```
airdropFee: "52009946125155410" // wei value
```

And it should be fine.

Comment: unbelievable, thanks it was so simple!